# PHP download adding underscores

Tags: php, download, path, attachment

I am trying to download the file that is passed in by the POST value. However if the file name is `"Functional requirements example"` when downloaded its name will be "__Functional"

Am I doing something very wrong here?
The downloaded file is in a folder called folder1. Unsure how to download the file from there. Any ideas how I can fix this so it downloads proper?

```
 <?php
    $ticType = $_POST['submit_param']; 
    header('Content-type: text/plain');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"/'.$ticType.'\"');
    readfile('folder1/'.$ticType);
    ?>
```

Comment: Remove backslashes and try again.. filename="/'.$ticType.'"'

Comment: This did it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not in error, you must not enclose your file name in `'` or `"` because they are treated as characters of the name. You are using two invalid characters: `/` and `"` that in a filename cannot be used, so PHP replace them with an underscore for every invalid character. Remove this chars and you should resolve!

Answer (score 0):

Its the spaces in your filename, and the following special characters will also cause underscores in the filename.

```
:, @, (), +, =, >, <, ?, {}, [], space
```

Not sure what the browser/ Http specs say about this. But other then that the name can be in `a-z A-Z 0-9` and the rest of special characters